# Shiny: multiple selectizeInput, one choice vector, discrete choices?

Tags: r, vector, shiny, shinydashboard

new to shiny. Hoping someone can help me out.

I have several selectizeInput's drawing choices from the same vector. My goal is to have values NOT show up in other Inputs after they have been chosen. ie. If value 1 has been chosen in Input 2, it should not be available in Input 1, 3 or 4.

```
ui<- shinyUI(fluidPage(

titlePanel("Selectize Test"),

sidebarPanel(
selectizeInput(
  "groupoptions1", "Group 1", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE
),
selectizeInput(
  "groupoptions2", "Group 2", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE
),
selectizeInput(
  "groupoptions3", "Group 3", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE
),
selectizeInput(
  "groupoptions4", "Group 4", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE
)

),

mainPanel(
  htmlOutput("grouplist")
)
))

server<- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

groupdata <- reactive({

  as.vector(1:30)

})

observe({
updateSelectizeInput(session, "groupoptions1", choices = groupdata())

updateSelectizeInput(session, "groupoptions2", choices = groupdata())

updateSelectizeInput(session, "groupoptions3", choices = groupdata())

updateSelectizeInput(session, "groupoptions4", choices = groupdata())
})


output$grouplist <- renderPrint({

  list(
    match(input$groupoptions1, groupdata()),
    match(input$groupoptions2, groupdata()),
    match(input$groupoptions3, groupdata()),
    match(input$groupoptions4, groupdata())
  )
})

})
```

I've tried having separate choice vectors for each selectizeInput that subtracts the other's selection, but then each time that vector updates all existing choices get wiped.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can and need to set the values when you update the input for the options inputs using the parameter selected:

```
 updateSelectizeInput(session, "groupoptions1", choices = groupdata1(),
                      selected=c(2,3))
```

You need to adapt the value according to your needs.
I reduced your example to two list and moved all the relevant parts to observe

```
  observe({
    vals1<-input$groupoptions1
    vals2<-input$groupoptions2

    cat("updata input ")
    cat(isolate(vals1))
    cat(" | ")
    cat(isolate(groupdata2()))
    cat("\n")
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "groupoptions1",
                         choices =  as.vector(1:10)[! 1:10 %in% vals2], 
                         selected=vals1)
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "groupoptions2", 
                         choices =as.vector(1:10)[! 1:10 %in% vals1], 
                         selected=vals2)


  })
```

Comment: One small caveat: The constant updating of the selectizeInputs causes the "dropdown" to collapse after an item is selected (because the new choice and selected values force the widget back into default, collapsed state). Not the end of the world but when there's 30 items in a list, that's a few extra clicks to get where you want. Any way you know to get around this? Is it possible to have the selectizeInput remain static until it loses focus? Like an action button, except the "action" is an input losing focus.

Comment: This is a bit tricky. You need to add JS code to the page. The idea has been shown here but for different controls (https://gist.github.com/xiaodaigh/7150112). However, this requires only minor adjustments).

 (btw. if my answer has helped you it would be kind if you would accept or up vote it)