# multiple selectizeInput from fileInput

Tags: file-io, shiny, selectize.js

I would like to have a user input a file (.csv) and from that file, two selectizeInputs will populate with the column names of the .csv.  One will ask the user which of the columns from their uploaded file is the y-variable and which of the columns is the x-variable.  This, I was able to do.

What I cannot do is the following:  I would like to get the selection from their y-variable to disappear from their x-variable choices in the x-variable drop-down menu.

Also,  I've used the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519213/shiny-multiple-selectizeinput-one-choice-vector-discrete-choices) to try to help, but they are not using the values from a fileInput.  As such, I cannot get my code, which is below, to work.  Thank you for any advice/help you can give.

```
ui<- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Test"),

  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput(inputId = "file1", label = "Upload File"),
    selectizeInput(
      "sampleyvars", "Y-vars", choices = NULL, multiple = FALSE
    ),
    selectizeInput(
      "samplevars", "X-vars", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE
    )

  ),

  mainPanel(h3("Nothing special")
  )
)

server<- function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    file1 <- input$file1
    if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
    dataSet <- read.csv(file=file1$datapath)

    vals1<-input$sampleyvars
    vals2<-input$samplevars

    updateSelectizeInput(session, "sampleyvars",
                         choices =  colnames(dataSet)[! vals1 %in% vals2])
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "samplexvars",
                         choices =colnames(dataSet)[! vals2 %in% vals1])
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had wrong `ID` of the widget for X variable: `samplevars` instead of `samplexvars` which you used in `update*` function. I changed it to the latter ID and also slightly tweaked your code to get the desired effect.

---

**Full example:**

```
  ui<- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Test"),

  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput(inputId = "file1", label = "Upload File"),
    selectizeInput(
      "sampleyvars", "Y-vars", choices = NULL, multiple = FALSE
    ),
    # you had ID here wrong
    selectizeInput(
      "samplexvars", "X-vars", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE
    )

  ),

  mainPanel(h3("Nothing special")
  )
)

server<- function(input, output, session) {

  data <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file1
    req(file1)
    dataSet <- read.csv(file=file1$datapath)
    vars <- colnames(dataSet)

    updateSelectizeInput(session, "sampleyvars", "Y-vars",
                         choices = vars, selected = vars[1])
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "samplexvars", choices = vars[-1], selected = vars[2])

    dataSet
  })

  observe({
    varX <- colnames(data())
    varX <- varX[!(varX %in% input$sampleyvars)]
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "samplexvars", "X-vars", choices = varX)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```

Comment: Ah...thank you so much!  That's exactly what I needed.